# How to get the root html element access in content script?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

In my chrome extension I want to inject an angular application Iframe as sidebar of a page. It is done by modifying the document body styles of a page in content script. But it has some limitations for specific web-pages.

Example:

In email if I inject my angular application Iframe as sidebar by customising document body styles like `width` and `marginRight`, some content is still not getting compressed to right (gmail). But I found that adjusting html tag style attribute can do the stuff using developer tools.
Unfortunately, I can't access the html element of a page in content script as it is **undefined** ( document.html ).

I even tried with `querySelector` approach but it does not work.

**Document.body approach :**

**content-script:**

**content.js:**

```
function injectAngularApplication() {
  var angularApplicationIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
  angularApplicationIframe.src = chrome.runtime.getURL('index.html');
  angularApplicationIframe.id = 'angularApplication';
  angularApplicationIframe.allow = 'clipboard-read; clipboard-write';
  angularApplicationIframe.className = 'angular_application_iframe';

  document.body.appendChild(angularApplicationIframe);

  document.body.style.marginRight = '30%';
  document.body.style.width = '70%';

}
```

**content.css:**

```
.angular_application_iframe {
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
    z-index: 9999;
    resize: horizontal;
    position: fixed;
}
```

The above works fine and injects my angular application as sidebar as expected but I want to get access for html tag as below:

Comment: what is `document.html`??? did you mean `document.documentElement` ... as for `as below:` there's nothing there

Comment: What is `index.html`? Is it part of your extension? If so, do you have the correct permissions set?

Comment: Use the new [sidePanel](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/sidePanel/) instead?